# Testing radio buttons in React 17 with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React (v17.0.2) component that has a controlled form with radio buttons and a submit button.  When a radio button is selected, the onRadioChange method is executed and sets the 'selected' state hook as the value of the selected radio button.  This works as intended in the browser.

```
const Test = () => {
  const beginner = 'Beginner';
  const intermediate = 'Intermediate';
  const expert = 'Expert';
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(beginner);
  const formSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('formSubmit executed');
    //will dispatch actions
  }
  const onRadioChange = (e) => {
    console.log('onRadioChange');
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="form">
      <form onSubmit={(e) => formSubmit(e)}>
        <div className="radio">
          <label id='beginner'>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value={beginner}
              checked={selected === beginner}
              onChange={(e) => onRadioChange(e)}
            />
            {beginner}
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="radio">
          <label id='intermediate'>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value={intermediate}
              checked={selected === intermediate}
              onChange={onRadioChange}
            />
            {intermediate}
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="radio">
          <label id='expert'>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value={expert}
              checked={selected === expert}
              onChange={onRadioChange}
            />
            {expert}
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="radio">
          Selected option is : {selected}
        </div>
        <button className="submitradio" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I test it with Enzyme (v3.11.0) using an Adapter I found (@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17)...

```
  it('should change the selected option when clicking on Intermediate', () => {
    const radio = wrapper.find('#intermediate');
    const selectedOne = wrapper.find('.selected');
    expect(selectedOne.props().children[1]).toBe('Beginner');

    radio.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Intermediate' } });

    const selectedTwo = wrapper.find('.selected');
    expect(selectedTwo.props().children[1]).toBe('Intermediate')
  });
```

...it doesn't fire 'onRadioChange'

```
    Expected: "Intermediate"
    Received: "Beginner"
      35 |
      36 |     const selectedTwo = wrapper.find('.selected');
    > 37 |     expect(selectedTwo.props().children[1]).toBe('Intermediate')
         |                                             ^
      38 |   });
      39 |
      40 | });
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.tsx:37:45)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem with the adapter?